# Does the spell Darkvision allow a PC to see through magical darkness?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, vision-and-light

Does the spell *darkvision* count as magical darkvision? If the BBEG cast *darkness*, and one of the PC's casts *darkvision*, are they able to see through the *darkness* spell?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Take the [tour]. You may be interested in this related question: [Does the Darkness spell block vision?](/questions/86510)

Answer (score 18):

### No, the PCs can't see through the darkness

The spell *darkvision* simply gives the PC darkvision just as if it were naturally granted by some other feature.

> You touch a willing creature to grant it the ability to see in the dark. For the duration, that creature has darkvision out to a range of 60 feet.

And the *darkness* spell specifically says that a creature with darkvision cannot see through it. It doesn't matter if it is magically granted or not.

> A creature with darkvision can't see through this darkness, and nonmagical light can't illuminate it.

So, no, a PC with darkvision (no matter how it is granted to them) cannot see through darkness from the *darkness* spell.

Note also that there's no such thing as magic darkvision or mundane darkvision in terms of the effects it has. The only difference is in how it is granted.

Comment: Might want to mention TrueSight and the Devil Sight Warlock Invocation.